# Facebook login user access token works in dev server but not in production using restfb

Tags: java, ios, tomcat, facebook-login, restfb

So this is kind of puzzling. I have an iOS app that uses Facebook login. the app gets a user token and sends that token to the server, where I'm using restfb with that token like so:

```
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(facebook_token, Version.VERSION_2_3);    
    com.restfb.types.User fbuser = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", com.restfb.types.User.class, Parameter.with("fields", "email,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large),about,hometown,languages"));
```

This works fine in dev server but in production server it gets stuck at that first line. Nothing logs after that.

On iOS, the only line that changes from dev to prod is the api URL string.

Comment: you are using the same app? What about the connection to Facebook already tried to access the graph API with curl from the production server?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out, some old dependencies where stuck, and maven wasn't installing the new ones.